# Binding Static variable from other class to listview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Iam trying to bring the values of static variable from the following class

```
public class LoginUserId
{
    public static int id { get; set; }
    public static string  username { get; set; } 

}
```

from here i created another class to get values as following

```
public class UsersList
{
    public static List<LoginUserId> Names { get; set; }
}
```

Now i have xaml page as

```
 <ListView ItemSelected="LoginUserList_OnItemSelected" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static lacal:UsersList.Names}}" IsVisible="True" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>                                
                            <Label Text="{Binding username}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" IsVisible="True"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

At output iam not getting anything just a blank page is appearing,please correct me where i went wrong.

Comment: Is your list in store local? Why didn't you use ViewModel binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your code as below

```
public class LoginUserId
{
    public  int id { get; set; }
    public  string username { get; set; }

}

public class UsersList
{
    public static List<LoginUserId> Names = new List<LoginUserId>() {
        new LoginUserId{id = 1, username = "No1"},
        new LoginUserId{id = 2, username = "No2"},
    };
}
```

The List **Names** must be static , but the property of object in it  should not be static , because we must initalize the variable for the model and assign the value for the properties, it's not steady.

Comment: Thank you for help@Cole Xia,but here username come dynamically.How i have to change that in order to get my requirement.

Comment: @sahithi Why username  must be static?

Comment: ,i actually have login form ,so the user who loggins their name comes to this static variable,if it is not static i am not getting the data,so placed static over there.

Comment: @sahithi if you set the username and id  to static ,then every LoginUserId has the same username and id .  why  don't you store the login form  to the local ?

Comment: @sahithi Per my understanding , you have a login form(list) , e.g , { (Tom,1),(Jason,2) , (Cole ,3 )}, right? every loginUser have different name ,so you can't set the name static.

Comment: Cole Xia@,iam trying pubnub chat application for android in cross plat form,so here iam trying to display those people who are logged in for the same channel,since iam at very basic knowledge i really  not able to understand how to achieve the list of subscribed people.

Comment: @sahithi I think what you need is  learning to store the list to local (using sq or file storage ) and gain them every time you want to display them  rather than static or none static...

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind to static variables with the way you did it in your XAML. When you use `Text="{Binding username}"` your property has to be a non static Property `public string username { get; set; }` if you want to bind to your static property then you have to use the `x:Static` way.

```
<Label Text="{x:Static local:YourViewModel.username}" />
```

of course you have to add a namespace of your viewModels to the `ContentPage`

Comment: Thanks for reply@Tomislav Eric,but iam not using the viewmodel here,is it necessary to have viewmodel,cant i get that directly from the "LoginUserId" class.